# Using services: mysql for codecption test in gitlab-ci fails with "Connection refused"

Tags: gitlab-ci, codeception

I have a CakePHP Application with codeception-plugin for testing.'
Locally I run it in a ddev docker environment and everything works fine.

Trying to run automated tests with gitlab-ci gives me  following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.1.0 (081978aa)
  on shared runner 601c0f11
Using Docker executor with image kevinliteon/cakephp:php7 ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:6a834f03bd02bb88cdbe0e289b9cd6056f1d42fa94792c524b4fddc474dab628 for mysql:latest ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...

*** WARNING: Service runner-601c0f11-project-94-concurrent-0-mysql-0 probably didn't start properly.

Health check error:
service "runner-601c0f11-project-94-concurrent-0-mysql-0-wait-for-service" timeout

Health check container logs:


Service container logs:
2018-10-04T12:12:18.904025613Z Initializing database
2018-10-04T12:12:18.925096235Z 2018-10-04T12:12:18.919745Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2018-10-04T12:12:18.925195518Z 2018-10-04T12:12:18.919970Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.12) initializing of server in progress as process 30
2018-10-04T12:12:50.330736417Z 2018-10-04T12:12:50.330487Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

*********

Pulling docker image kevinliteon/cakephp:php7 ...
Using docker image sha256:bd4a83b02647ad93a356b343d2ce5ae3a9a1177aea2cd76c61b009abc7df8990 for kevinliteon/cakephp:php7 ...
Running on runner-601c0f11-project-94-concurrent-0 via d7f4a5e71b47...
Fetching changes...
Removing vendor/
HEAD is now at 92cb022 test
Checking out 92cb0223 as deployment...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache
$ vendor/bin/codecept run Unit
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.9
Powered by PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

In Db.php line 308:

  Db: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused while creating PDO connection
```

My gitlab-ci.yml (partly):

```
services:
- mysql:latest

variables:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql123456789
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
  MYSQL_USER: db
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: db

build:
  ...

codecept:Unit:
  stage: test
  script:
  - vendor/bin/codecept run Unit
```

In my codeception.yml I configured the Db module:

```
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=mysql;dbname=test_db'
            user: 'db'
            password: 'db'
            cleanup: true # reload dump between tests
            populate: true # load dump before all tests
            reconnect: true
```

I also tryed using the root user - without success.

Problem is, that I can not connect to the DB for whatever reasons... Maybe the warnings while initializing the service container have something to do with that, but I could not figure out how to fix them or if this is the problem.

I really tried a lot of things without any success! Basically my code depends on the documentations of gitlab-ci and codeception so it should work.

Anybody implemented this scenario successfully or know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer how I solved it:
First thing was, I had to add the env-varibale "db_dsn" like this:

```
export db_dsn="mysql://user:paswd@host/db"
```

Then I still got the health-check error. Only way I found to successfully setup was to use another docker image for the db-service. I choose "mariadb:latest" - and then it worked for me.